# Set Focus of TextBox inside listview

Tags: listview

i have listview control and textbox inside the listview on textbox change event i loop thru listview and multiply textbox 1 value to textbox 2 and show in textbox3 it works ok, i want when user press tab on textbox 1 so it goes to textbox 2 but its not happening.

here is my code html and page behind

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataKeyNames="CategoryId">

    <ItemTemplate>

   <%-- //ajax update panel to have asyn call--%>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                  Item:  <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'></asp:Label>  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                   QTY:  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="qty" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" Text="0" ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                   Item Price: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" Text="0"  ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                 <td>
                    &nbsp;
                 Total:(QTY X Item Price)   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Enabled='false'></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <%--// trigger to call textbox change event  on asyn call--%>
            <Triggers >
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="TextBox1" EventName ="TextChanged" />
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="TextBox2" EventName ="TextChanged" />
       </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

page behind

```
 public void cal()
    {
        //loop thru listview
        foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
        {

            //make vairables and get control value inside listview in variable to be call for calculation
            TextBox QTY = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox1");
            TextBox ItemPrice = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox2");

            TextBox TotalPrice = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox3");

            if (QTY.Text != "0" && ItemPrice.Text != "0" && QTY.Text != string.Empty && ItemPrice.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                // make int or decimal variable to multiply QTY and Item Price textbox value ==   i conver both QTY and Item Price textbox to int using int.parse method
                int totalprice = int.Parse(QTY.Text) * int.Parse(ItemPrice.Text);

                TotalPrice.Text = totalprice.ToString();


            }




        }



    }
```

Comment: if there is solution thru javasript or jquery to multiply textbox1 to textbox12 and show in textbox3 inside listview is also welcome main problem is to set focus of next textbox on tab press thanks

Answer (score 0):

With your code, every time user change value of *TextBox1* or *TextBox2* then press tab, the page will be submitted and the content of page will be updated. So *TextBox2* can not get focus when user change value of *TextBox1* and press tab.

You could convert the calculation to jQuery function and binding it to change event of your textbox like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".quantity,.price").change(function(e) {
       var container = $(e.currentTarget).closest("table");
       var quantity = $(".quantity", container).val();
       var price = $(".price", container).val();
       if ($.isNumeric(quantity) && $.isNumeric(price) 
          && parseInt(quantity) != 0 && parseInt(price) != 0) {
            var total = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(price);
          $(".total", container).val(total);
       } 
    });
});
```

Don't forget to remove *AsyncPostBackTrigger* to disable the postback when value of textbox changed.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataKeyNames="CategoryId">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
           <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                      Item:  <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'></asp:Label>  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                       QTY:  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="quantity" Text="0" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                       Item Price: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="price" Text="0"  ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>

                     <td>
                        &nbsp;
                     Total:(QTY X Item Price)   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="total" Enabled='false'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I've created the sample at this link https://jsfiddle.net/oomsvgk0/1/, you could check it.

Comment: my textboxes are inside the asp dot net listview will your code work with textbox inside the listview please advice

Comment: I've updated the script to make it work with controls inside the listview.  The main update is that I've changed it to use class selector instead id of controls. Please check.

Comment: hi its setting the focus on tab press but not performing the calculation

Comment: Have you placed the script inside $(document).ready function?

Comment: yes i add it inside the script tag but its not calculating it

Comment: You had to place it inside $(document).ready and also add jquery to your page. I've updated the answer, please check.